# Control Sendmail with Swiftmailer in Symfony

Tags: symfony, sendmail, swiftmailer

The following Code works on the server i am using (Hosteurope WebPack):

```
mail('someone@example.net', 'some subject', 'sendmail is working', 'From: me@example.org', "");
```

The following Code isn't:

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
  ->setSubject('some subject')
  ->setFrom('me@example.org')
  ->setTo('someone@example.net')
  ->setBody('sendmail via swiftmail is working');
$mailer = $this->get('mailer');
$logger = new Swift_Plugins_Loggers_ArrayLogger();
$mailer->registerPlugin(new Swift_Plugins_LoggerPlugin($logger));
$mailer->send($message);
```

And in $logger writes this error:

```
++ Starting Swift_Transport_SendmailTransport
<< 
!! Expected response code 220 but got code "", with message "" (code: 0)"
  ...
```

My configuration is:

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: "sendmail"
    sender_address: "me@example.org"
```

I do not see why one is working and the other isn't since, as far as i can tell, the call should be identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the Sendmail Transport does not send the From Header (as expected).
Using "mail" as the transport worked for me:

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: "sendmail"
    sender_address: "me@example.org"
```

Hope this might help others having trouble with Hosteurope and sendmail/sending mails.

Answer (score 1):

If your are using sendmail with symfony, it may happen that you have to pass some additional options. For example:

`'/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i'`

To find out which options must be passed, create a `phpinfo.php` on your server,

```
<?php
phpinfo();
>
```

run it and find the entries which start with:

```
sendmail_from
sendmail_path
```

Either of them will show `/usr/sbin/sendmail -some_options`

In order to get it working in symfony, you can't paste it in the `config.yml` directly - at least in my experience.

Open up `services.yml` and add:

```
swiftmailer.mailer.default.transport:
  class:     Swift_SendmailTransport
  arguments: ['/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i']
```

Where `arguments` is the path from the php entry from above.

Then set `config.yml` to:

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: sendmail
```

Or, if you like to separate dev and prod env, paste it in one of them.